# __spark_conf__.zip: No such file or directory

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, azure-data-factory

When I am submitting a Spark activity from Azure Data factory V2 on HDInsight cluster I am getting the error-

```
Application application_1524230454528_0060 failed 5 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1524230454528_0060_000005 exited with exitCode: -1000
    For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://hn1-rbc-cl.tsgjwtochfbexi5wvtaxuipmmg.rx.internal.cloudapp.net:8088/cluster/app/application_1524230454528_0060 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
    Diagnostics: wasb://rbc-cluster-2018-04-20t13-11-42-670z@rbcdemo.blob.core.windows.net/user/livy/.sparkStaging/application_1524230454528_0060/__spark_conf__.zip: No such file or directory.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: wasb://rbc-cluster-2018-04-20t13-11-42-670z@rbcdemo.blob.core.windows.net/user/livy/.sparkStaging/application_1524230454528_0060/__spark_conf__.zip: No such file or directory.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getFileStatusInternal(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Can someone help me figure out what the issue is or there is any other workaround to run spark jobs via Azure Data factory pipelines. I am stuck on this and could not proceed. As per Azure Data Factory documentation, I tried placing my files in ./files folder in the container where my spark jar is present. But still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What's your HDI cluster version and the version of Java used to develop your program, please make sure the versions are the same.

BTW, HDI cluster 3.5+ require java 8, while the earlier versions require java 7.